# How do I do bind to property title of a marker from google maps with vuejs?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working with api google maps now I am development with vuejs now exist the posibility from bind a property to the property title from markers, for example
this is my component on vuejs

```
Vue.component('root-map',{
  template: `
  <div id="sidebar_builder"
  style="width: 100%; height: 600px;">
  </div>
  `,
  data: function(){
   return {
    map:null,
    marker:{
      title: 'hello'
    }
}
 },
mounted: function () {
this.$nextTick(function () {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng
};
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('sidebar_builder'),mapOptions);
  var marker_icon= new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                title: this.marker.title}); // the most important part
   marker_icon.setMap(this.map);
  });
}
});
```

Now when I want change the property markers.title='I change' and happend nothing, the markers on the maps keep 'hello', could you please how do I do it ? If can do it without use method native from api google maps thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use watch

```
watch: {
  marker() {
    this.reDrawMarkers()
  }
}
```

more info vue watcher https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

if you dont know how to redraw markers also you can look google documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove